# How to pass arguments to the threading.Timer callback?

Tags: python, timer

I tried this code:

```
import threading

def hello(arg, kargs):
    print(arg)

t = threading.Timer(2, hello, "bb")
t.start()

while 1:
    pass
```

The output is just `b` instead of `bb`.

How can I pass arguments to the callback properly?

If I remove the `kargs` parameter from `hello`, I get an exception that says `TypeError: hello() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Why? Where did the `kargs` value come from in the first code?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`Timer` expects a sequence (normally, a list or tuple) of arguments and a mapping (normally, a dict) of keyword arguments, so pass a list instead:

```
import threading

def hello(arg):
    print(arg)

t = threading.Timer(2, hello, ["bb"])
t.start()

while 1:
    pass
```

Since `"bb"` is an iterable, the `Timer` will iterate over it and use each element as a separate argument; `threading.Timer(2, hello, "bb")` is equivalent to `threading.Timer(2, hello, ["b", "b"])`.

Use a dictionary to pass any [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) to the callback, for example:

```
def hello(arg, kwarg):
    print('arg is', arg, 'and kwarg is', kwarg)

t = threading.Timer(2, hello, ["bb"], {'kwarg': 1})
```

Comment: Here's a link to the [section on keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) in a more up-to-date version of tutorial (although the information looks about the same).

Comment: Google kept dropping me in that version.  Ironically, the older version is easier to read; they've gone so far overboard with the styling in the newer ones that it's distracting, with the background color spastically jumping back and forth.

Answer (score 5):

The third argument to `Timer` is a sequence. Passing `"bb"` as that sequence means that `hello` gets the elements of that sequence (`"b"` and `"b"`) as separate arguments (`arg` and `kargs`). Put `"bb"` in a list, and `hello` will get the string as the first argument:

```
t = threading.Timer(2, hello, ["bb"])
```

Presumably, `hello` was intended to have parameters like:

```
def hello(*args, **kwargs):
```

See [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901) for a detailed explanation of this syntax.