# How does using a function (callback) as an argument to another function work in Python?

Tags: python, function, arguments, higher-order-functions

Suppose I have some code like:

```
def myfunc(anotherfunc, extraArgs):
    # somehow call `anotherfunc` here, passing it the `extraArgs`
    pass
```

I want to pass another existing function as the `anotherfunc` argument, and a list or tuple of arguments as `extraArgs`, and have `myfunc` call the passed-in function with those arguments.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502068/is-there-a-formal-name-for-a-function-that-accepts-a-functions-as-an-argument/47634215#47634215

Answer (score 157):

Yes, this is possible. `myfunc` can call the passed-in function like:

```
def myfunc(anotherfunc, extraArgs):
    anotherfunc(*extraArgs)
```

Here is a fully worked example:

```
>>> def x(a, b):
...     print('a:', a, 'b:', b)
... 
>>> def y(z, t):
...     z(*t)
... 
>>> y(x, ('hello', 'manuel'))
a: hello b: manuel
```

Comment: can extraArgs be a function as well ? if so how do you call it ?

Comment: @sekai Yes, extraArgs can be a function too.

Comment: where is this documented?

Comment: @4dc0 I don't think it's *directly* documented; it's just a natural consequence of how Python's data model works. Everything that can be bound to a name is an object; objects can be passed to functions; functions can be bound to a name (that's what happens when you use `def`); therefore, functions can be passed to functions. That said, you may be interested in https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/functional.html, which shows elementary techniques that *make use of* this reality, and shows off some of the standard library goodies *designed to capitalize* on it.

Answer (score 37):

Here's another way using `*args` (and optionally `**kwargs` as well):

```
def a(x, y):
    print(x, y)

def b(other, function, *args, **kwargs):
    function(*args, **kwargs)
    print(other)

b('world', a, 'hello', 'dude')
```

Output

```
hello dude
world
```

Note that `function`, `*args`, and `**kwargs` must appear in that order and must be the last arguments to the function (`b`) that calls `function`.

Comment: More infos about *args & **kwargs can be found here https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Answer (score 19):

Functions in Python are first-class objects. However, the function definition [should be slightly different](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
def myfunc(anotherfunc, extraArgs, extraKwArgs):
    return anotherfunc(*extraArgs, **extraKwArgs)
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure, that is why python implements the following methods where the first parameter is a function:

- `map(function, iterable, ...)` - Apply function to every item of iterable
  and return a list of the results.
- `filter(function, iterable)` - Construct a list from those elements
  of iterable for which function returns true.
- `reduce(function, iterable [,initializer])` - Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of `iterable`, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value.
- [lambdas](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

Comment: See also: https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/functional.html. The builtins also include `sort`, `min` and `max` which accept a `key` keyword argument that is expected to be a callable.

Comment: I don't really think lambdas belong in the same category, though. They aren't a built-in function (nor "method"), but a *syntax*; and a lambda's first parameter definitely does not need to accept a function. In fact, a lambda doesn't need to have parameters at all.

Answer (score 3):

A function can be a parameter to another function, and a function can return another function.

Here is an example:

```
def out_func(a):
    def in_func(b):
        print(a + b + b + 3)
    return in_func
 
obj = out_func(1)
print(obj(5)) # outputs 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Use the function like any other: `anotherfunc(*extraArgs)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to call two or more functions at once, by using a call to one function as an argument to the other:

```
def anotherfunc(inputarg1, inputarg2):
    pass
def myfunc(func = anotherfunc):
    print(func)

myfunc(anotherfunc(inputarg1, inputarg2))
```

This will cause `myfunc` to print the return value from the `anotherfunc` call (i.e., `None`).

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

[Decorators](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/decorators.html) are very powerful in Python since they programmers to pass a function as an argument, and can also define one function inside another function.

```
def decorator(func):
    def insideFunction():
        print("This is inside function before execution")
        func()
    return insideFunction

def func():
    print("I am argument function")

func_obj = decorator(func) 
func_obj()
```

Output:

```
This is inside function before execution
I am argument function
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-function-decorators-and-chain-them-together/1594484

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

Yes, this is possible.

In the example in the question, the `anotherfunc` parameter for `myfunc` is an example of a [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234), and `myfunc` is therefore an example of a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) (hereafter, HOF).

A simple example of both sides of the equation - writing the HOF and giving it a callback - might look like:

```
def higher_order(a_callback):
    print("I will call:", a_callback)
    a_callback()

def my_callback():
    print("my_callback was called")

higher_order(my_callback)
```

Note carefully that the example passes `my_callback` - using [**just the function name, not** with parentheses after it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933). Incorrectly writing `higher_order(my_callback())` [would mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792629) to **call `my_callback` first**, and pass **the return value** ([here, that would be `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067013)) to `higher_order`. This will cause a [`TypeError`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631401), since [`None` is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768865).

In the function itself, **nothing special needs to be done** in order to accept another function as a parameter, nor to use it by calling it. Inside `higher_order`, `a_callback` is the local name for whatever function was passed in (here, `my_callback`); functions are called by writing their name, `(`, the appropriate arguments, and `)`; so that is all that `higher_order` needs to do in order to use that passed-in function.

#### Writing a HOF

Suppose we attempt to define `def my_func(other_func, func_args):`, where `other_func` will be a callback. Within the function, `other_func` is simply a name for the callback that was passed in, and calling it works **the same way as calling any other function**. We need a name (or any other expression that evaluates to the [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234) that should be called), then `(`, then any appropriate arguments for the call, then `)`. Supposing for example that `func_args` should be a [sequence of variable arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680) to the callable, we can make this call by [unpacking the arguments in the call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727). Thus:

```
def my_func(other_func, func_args):
    other_func(*func_args)
```

Similarly, a callback that requires keyword arguments could receive them from another parameter that will be passed a `dict` (or other mapping), which the HOF could pass to the callback with `**` unpacking. Thus:

```
def my_func(other_func, func_args, func_kwargs):
    other_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
```

Of course, **we are by no means limited to such basic logic**. `my_func` works like any other function. It could do any other arbitrary work before or after calling `other_func`; it could `return` or otherwise make use of the `other_func` result; it could call `other_func` more than once (or conditionally not at all); it could use its own logic to determine arguments to pass to the callback (perhaps even determine them locally and not have parameters like `func_args` or `func_kwargs` at all), etc.

#### Passing a callback function to a HOF

In order to use this HOF, the calling code requires two things: an appropriate callable to pass as the callback (i.e., its signature must be compatible with how the HOF will call it), and the appropriate code for a call to the HOF itself.

Continuing the above example, suppose we have a callback like

```
def my_callback(a, b, /, **c):
    print(f'a = {a}; b = {b}; c = {c}')
```

Since the previous `my_func` will use `*` and `**` for the call, applied to input from the caller, there is no particular restriction on the signature of `my_callback`. However, since `my_func` will receive the `a` and `b` arguments from `*func_args`, and since `my_func` [marks these parameters as positional-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477827), the `func_args` passed to `my_func` will need to be a sequence of length 2. (`func_kwargs` is supposed to be a dictionary anyway; it will be unpacked for the call to the callback, and then the callback will [pack it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901).

Thus:

```
def my_func(other_func, func_args, func_kwargs):
    other_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)

def my_callback(a, b, /, **c):
    print(f'a = {a}; b = {b}; c = {c}')

# call `my_func`, giving it the callback `my_callback`
# as well as appropriate arguments to call the callback:
my_func(my_callback, [1, 2], {'example': 3})
```

#### Other kinds of callbacks

Since the HOF simply *calls* the callback, it doesn't actually care whether the callback is a function. Taking advantage of [duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130), we can also pass e.g. a class. This is especially useful for HOFs that use a callback for "type-checking" (e.g. the standard library `argparse` does this):

```
def ask_user_for_value(type_checker):
    while True:
        try:
            return type_checker(input('give me some input: '))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'invalid input ({e}); try again')

# using an existing type:
ask_user_for_value(int)

# using a custom function for verification:
def capital_letter(text):
    if len(text) != 1:
        raise ValueError('not a single character')
    if not (text.isupper() and text.isalpha()):
        raise ValueError('not an uppercase letter')
    return text

ask_user_for_value(capital_letter)

# using an enum: (in 3.11 this could use StrEnum)
from enum import Enum
class Example(Enum):
    ONE = 'one'
    TWO = 'two'

ask_user_for_value(Example)

# using a bound method of an instance:
class Exact: # only allow the specified string
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def check(self, value):
        if value != self._value:
            raise ValueError(f'must be {self._value!r}')
        return value

ask_user_for_value(Exact('password').check)
```

#### Other ways to use callbacks

Aside from defining a HOF, a callback function can simply be stored in a data structure - such as a `list`, `dict` or as an attribute of some class instance - and then used later. The key insight is that **functions are objects** in Python, so they can be stored in this way, and any *expression that evaluates* to the function object can be used to call the function.

Examples:

```
def my_callback():
    print('my_callback was called')

# in a list
funcs = [my_callback]
for i in funcs:
    i()

# in a dict
funcs = {'my_callback': my_callback}
funcs['my_callback']()

# in a class instance
class Example:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self._callback = callback

    def use_callback(self):
        self._callback()

instance = Example()
instance.use_callback()
```

#### Special case: providing arguments that the HOF won't

Sometimes, we want to use an existing callback function, but it requires additional arguments besides what the HOF will provide. This is especially important when working with a HOF that comes from third-party code. Many libraries are specifically designed to accept arbitrary parameters to forward to the callback (for example, [the standard library `threading`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415672)), but others are not (for example, using [the standard library `timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) with a callable rather than a string for the code to test).

In the latter case, arguments must be "bound" to the callback before passing it to the HOF.

**See [Python Argument Binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922) to understand how to do this** - it is beyond the scope of this answer.

The same logic, of course, applies when a callback is stored for later use in other ways (e.g. as a `command` provided when creating [a `Button` in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302)).

Answer (score 0):

```
def x(a):
    print(a)
    return a

def y(a):
    return a

y(x(1))
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Comment: You are not passing function as an argument here, instead the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
def x(a):
    print(a)
    return a

def y(func_to_run, a):
    return func_to_run(a)

y(x, 1)
```