# Python NoneType object is not callable (beginner)

Tags: python, nonetype

It tells me line 1 and line 5 (new to debugging/programming, not sure if that helps)

```py
def hi():
    print('hi')


def loop(f, n):  # f repeats n times
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        f()
        loop(f, n-1)
```

```sh
>>> loop(hi(), 5)
hi
f()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Why does it give me this error?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You want to pass the function *object* `hi` to your `loop()` function, not the result of a *call* to `hi()` (which is `None` since `hi()` doesn't return anything).

So try this:

```
>>> loop(hi, 5)
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
```

Perhaps this will help you understand better:

```
>>> print hi()
hi
None
>>> print hi
<function hi at 0x0000000002422648>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Also, you might want to call your function `recurse` or something similar since it doesn't actually loop...

Comment: For anyone in the future seeing this after decorating a class/function: make sure you return something from the implementation of the decorator!

Answer (score 6):

> Why does it give me that error?

Because your first parameter you pass to the `loop` function is [None](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None) but your function is expecting an callable object, which [None](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None) object isn't.

Therefore you have to pass the callable-object which is in your case the `hi` function object.

```
def hi():     
  print 'hi'

def loop(f, n):         #f repeats n times
  if n<=0:
    return
  else:
    f()             
    loop(f, n-1)    

loop(hi, 5)
```

Comment: What if the hi function took an argument, e.g. text, and printed the string passed as the variable text. How would that be handled?

Comment: try `lambda arg: hi(arg)`

Comment: With hi taking an argument, `loop(hi, 5)` still runs, outputting the expected string, eg 'hi'+<your passed text>. @OlivierdeBroqueville

Answer (score 3):

You should not pass the call function hi() to the loop() function, This will give the result.

```
def hi():     
  print('hi')

def loop(f, n):         #f repeats n times
  if n<=0:
    return
  else:
    f()             
    loop(f, n-1)    

loop(hi, 5)            # Do not use hi() function inside loop() function
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable " but for a different issue.
With the above clues, i was able to debug and got it right!
The issue that i faced was :
I had the custome Library written and my file wasnt recognizing it although i had mentioned it

```
example: 
Library           ../../../libraries/customlibraries/ExtendedWaitKeywords.py
the keywords from my custom library were recognized and that error  was resolved only after specifying the complete path, as it was not getting the callable function.
```