# TypeError: "NoneType" object is not callable in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

**below imported packages and models which is define to allow to access the building operations,**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSpro
```

**Now here is the coding of the created model,  I think it is too importat to describe the model,**

> Rescale the images shapes,

```
train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
```

> Fixed the dataset directory and access the data,

```
train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory(
    'cnn_happy_NotHapp/Basedata/training/',
    target_size=(200,200),
    batch_size = 3,
    class_mode = 'binary')
validation_dataset = validation.flow_from_directory(
    'cnn_happy_NotHapp/Basedata/validation/',
    target_size=(200,200),
    batch_size = 3,
    class_mode = 'binary')
```

> Create the CNN model

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 3)),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                    ##################################
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(132,(3,3), activation='relu'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                    ##################################
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                    ##################################
                                    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    ###################################
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
                                    ###################################
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])
```

> Compile the model

```
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              metrics = ['accuracy '])
```

> Fit the model and please noticed here because i faced problem here,

```
model_fit = model.fit(train_dataset,
                      steps_per_epoch=3,
                      epochs= 10,
                      validation_data = validation_dataset)     #error is here
```

> Below the error section, I request all of stactoverflow members for
> carefully read and help me for solving this error,

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-85ae786a1bf1> in <module>()
      2                       steps_per_epoch=3,
      3                       epochs= 10,
----> 4                       validation_data = validation_dataset)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    805       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    806       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 807       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    808     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    809       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

**Note:** I am suffering from this error , I can't solved it and advanced thanks who are try to solve it and comment here for sharing the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python NoneType object is not callable (beginner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768865/python-nonetype-object-is-not-callable-beginner)

Comment: No, I have seen that and try to understand but i don't.

Comment: This seems to be telling you that the value `self._stateless_fn` is `None`, which doesn't work when you treat it like a function and try to call it.  I don't know the modules being used here, so maybe this isn't as simple as I'm making it, but...your code doesn't mention `_stateless_fn` at all, so there's no way for us to know why it is `None`.

Comment: Imdadul Haque, Is your issue resolved now? Else, please can you share complete code  or Colab file to replicate your issue. Thanks!

Comment: @ImdadulHaque have you managed to solve the issue? It seems kinda new and there's no proper answer for it.

Comment: @AlirezaMoradi, yea, I could solve it.

Comment: @ImdadulHaque Could you share how you solved it?

Comment: @AlirezaMoradi Please follow the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@AlirezaMoradi please concern here,

I made a mistakes below,

> In compile section of the model,

```
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001),
              metrics = ['accuracy '])  #'accuracy ' it will be 'accuracy'
```

That means,for my mistakes I add **white space** and after removing It solved.

*I was busy that's why it is late for sharing the solution and I am sorry for late.*