# Right Click using a hotkey in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pydirectinput

import pyautogui

import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey('a', pydirectinput.rightClick())

keyboard.wait('esc')
```

I want to run the right-click mouse function using a hotkey in Python but the error I was getting is that the "NoneType" object is not callable.

Can Anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python NoneType object is not callable (beginner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768865/python-nonetype-object-is-not-callable-beginner)

Comment: @Robert No, I don't think that is the problem. He received an error saying that NoneType is not callable.

Comment: I need a keypressed to run this code pydirectinput.rightClick(100,100,duration=0.5)

Comment: @PortMe that **is** the problem. The second argument to `keyboard.add_hotkey` should be a callable / function. They've written `pydirectinput.rightClick()` instead they should be writing `pydirectinput.rightClick` without the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pydirectinput
from pynput import keyboard

def on_key_pressed(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.space:
        # When the spacebar is released, perform a right-click action
        pydirectinput.rightClick(100, 100, duration=0.5)

# Start listening for key events
with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_key_pressed) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).