# Is it possible to not return anything from a function in python? (What happens if the function reaches the end without `return`ing?)

Tags: python, function

Consider this code:

```
def foo(foo_input):
    if 0 <= foo_input <= 100:
        return f_input
```

This returns `None` in the case where `foo_input > 100`. But could it actually *not* return anything? Or does a function always have to return something?

---

<sub>See also: [return, return None, and no return at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/)</sub>

Comment: Why does it bother you the function returns `None`?

Comment: chaining functions, and if I was going to have to write try : except clauses for each of them (because of the none that is passed)

Comment: use969617: What would happen if no output was returned? If it was the execution being skipped, then you can get the same functionality using an if statement to check for ``None`` - although if it's more likely you will get a result than None, catching exceptions is a better idea, as Python follows the _ask for forgiveness, not permission_ principle.

Comment: I was wondering if I could get away without even having to use if statements :)

Comment: Well, remember that exceptions fall through, so if you want to catch an error due to ``None`` anywhere in your process, then you can simply wrap your entire block in a catch for ``TypeError``s. Obviously only wrap the segment for which this is necessary, but there is no need for a ton of the same ``try ... except ...`` blocks

Comment: @Lattyware - do you know of an example that I could view?

Comment: @user969617 An example of what, sorry?

Comment: @Lattyware - sorry , of wrapping a black in a catch for TypeError

Comment: @user969617 Literally just ``try: ... except TypeError: ...`` where ``...`` is any python code you want (properly indented and with new lines the comment doesn't give me, naturally). See the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) for more.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Functions always return something (at least `None`, when no return-statement was reached during execution and the end of the function is reached).

Another case is when they are interrupted by exceptions.
In this case exception handling will "dominate over the stack" and you will return to the appropriate `except` or get some nasty error :)

Regarding your problem I must say there are two possibilities:
Either you have something to return or you do not have.

- If you have something to return then do so, if not then don't.
- If you rely on something being returned that has a certain type but you cannot return anything meaningful of this type then `None` will tell the caller that this was the case (
  There is no better way to tell the caller that "nothing" is returned then by `None`, so check for it and you will be fine)

Answer (score 31):

No. If a `return` statement is not reached before the end of the function then an implicit `None` is returned.

Answer (score 12):

If a return statement is not reached, the function returns `None`.

```
def set_x():
    x = 2
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you really are trying to do.  Here are a few things you might like:

```
def foo(foo_input, foo_default):
    if 0 <= foo_input <= 100:
        return f_input
    else:
        return foo_default


def foo(foo_input):
    if 0 <= foo_input <= 100:
        return f_input
    raise ValueError, "foo_input was not in range [0, 100]"
```

Wait, you said "filter".  Are you filtering a series of values and you just want to extract the ones that meet a criteria?  That's easy in Python:

```
def foo_check(x):
    return 0 <= x <= 100

filtered_list = [x for x in unfiltered_sequence if foo_check(x)]
```

And you said "chaining functions".  Again that's easy if we are talking about filtering a sequence:

```
def foo_filter(seq):
    for x in seq:
        if 0 <= x <= 100:
            yield x

def other_filter(seq):
    for x in seq:
        if meets_criterion(x):
            yield x


def do_the_task(seq):
    for x in other_filter(foo_filter(seq)):
        do_something(x)
```

EDIT: Here is a nice introduction to iterators and generators in Python.  http://www.learningpython.com/2009/02/23/iterators-iterables-and-generators-oh-my/

Comment: and this would be fine if I was filtering 100 or so a second?

Comment: There is no reason to use a function there, it's clearer just to do it as ``[x for x in sequence if 0 <= x <= 100]``.

Comment: @steveha: why use a list comprehension when there is a built-in `filter` function? `filtered_list = filter(foo_filter, unfiltered_sequence)`

Comment: @Lattyware: I would say otherwise. Also it depends on how used the reader is to the one or the other construction. And as a lazy programmer I would say: it is shorter :)

Comment: in a larger context, I am reading a serial Connection, ( strings between 0 - 1023 ), I am filtering out strings that contain characters as well ie. '102?3' , this filter is the third in a series, that then only allows a through ones between 1-100.

Comment: If you were filtering 100 a second, this would be fine.  For highest performance in Python you should write "lazy" code that doesn't build temporary lists and then delete them, so the `yield` code is good for chaining filters.

Comment: this is why i wasn't touching list comprehension

Comment: or at least I didn't think I was

Comment: @steveha Or just use generator expressions. ``(x for x in (x for x in unfiltered_iterator if other_filter(x)) if foo_check(x))``.

Comment: @Nobody, if you are part of the functional programming community, you probably prefer `filter()`.  The Python community usually prefers list comprehensions.  Also, in Python 2.x, `filter()` is not lazy and always builds an object (by default a list).

Comment: I'm using python 3.X - and I'm quite partial to Haskell

Comment: @Lattyware, I agree that for this simple example putting the expression in the list comprehension is reasonable.  I have a tendency to break things out into functions for readability, especially when answering questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @steveha Naturally readability is a judgement call and what works in one situation won't always work in others.

Comment: @steveha: Well I am not that "functional" ^^ And for me it seemed always the other way round. Also I do not see why the filter function should create an additional list compared to the comprehension.

Comment: In Python 3.x, the built-in `filter()` is lazy.  But you can also write a loop that will `yield` answers as I showed, and you can also write a generator expression.

Comment: @Nobody, fire up Python 2.x, and from the `>>>` prompt type `help(filter)` and read what it says.  It says, quite plainly, that it will return a list, a tuple, or a string.  Now fire up Python 3.x and do the same thing; it says, quite plainly, that it will return an iterator.  So maybe you don't see why it should do it, but I am talking about what it actually does.  I think the reason is historical: I think `filter()` was introduced before iterators were added.  Of course in Python 2.x you can use `itertools.ifilter()` or write your own function that loops and calls `yield`.

Comment: @steveha what constitutes a 'sequence'? if they are numbers read from a serial connection - they are still a sequence?

Comment: A "sequence" means anything that Python can iterate over.  A list or tuple is a sequence.  A string is a sequence of characters.  Any iterator is a sequence as well (generators are a kind of iterator).  You should probably have a function that reads the serial data and calls `yield` to return it.  If you have a class wrapping your serial port, the class instance should work as an iterator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator

Comment: @steveha: Well of course filter returns a list but the list comprehension does this too and that was what I asked for. But lets not stretch this discussion unnecessary. Thank you for pointing me at the `help` I forget about it from time to time (I am a google zombie :).

Comment: Nice answer. A noob would have found it useful to have an explanation about the use of ``yield``, as opposed to ``return`` or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I sort of like the implicit `return None` but [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) flags it as bad style, warning:

> Either all return statements in a function should return an
>   expression, or none of them
>   should.pylint(inconsistent-return-statements)

Hence,

```
def foo(foo_input):
    if 0 <= foo_input <= 100:
        return f_input
    return None
```

might be better style, even if they are functionally the same.

---

More info available [here](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/1.8.html), where the Pylint change-log states:

> A new Python checker was added to warn about
>   inconsistent-return-statements. A function or a method has
>   inconsistent return statements if it returns both explicit and
>   implicit values ...
>
> According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), if any return statement returns an expression, any
>   return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state
>   this as return None, and an explicit return statement should be
>   present at the end of the function (if reachable).

Answer (score 1):

***Functions always return something.***

All 3 functions below return **`None`**:

```py
def test1():
    print("test1")
    return None

def test2():
    print("test2")
    return

def test3():
    print("test3")
```