# What does return with nothing mean in python?

Tags: python

I'm viewing the source code of a project now. In which I saw a function like this.

```
def func(x):
    if condition_a:
        return
    if condition_b:
        return
    process_something
```

What does this return with nothing do here?

Comment: Would 'return None' be a more explicit thus a more Pythonic expression here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "`return` with nothing" exits the function at that line and returns `None`. As [Python's docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) say:

> If an expression list is present, it is evaluated, else `None` is substituted.
>
> `return` leaves the current function call with the expression list (or `None`) as return value.

In flow control, I've seen it commonly used when some sort of condition is encountered that makes it impossible to execute the rest of the function; for example,

```
def getDataFromServer():
    if serverNotResponding():
        return
    # do important stuff here which requires the server to be running
```

Comment: Would 'return None' a better expression here?

Comment: @Zen See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/python-return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all) question