# Differentiate between no returned value and return None

Tags: python

Is there a way to differentiate these two returned values?

```
>>> sort([1, 2, 3])
None

>>> dict(a=1).get('b')
None
```

The first returns `None` because there is no returned value. The second returns `None` as the returned value.

Comment: `None` is `None` my friend.

Comment: If you want to distinguish you'll have to distinguish something else besides the return values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function returning `None`, just returning or allowing execution to reach the end of the function is basically the same thing.

Consider the following functions:

```
def func1():
        return None

def func2():
        pass

def func3():
        return
```

If we now dissasemble the functions' bytecode (the `dis`module can do that), we see the following

```
func1():
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
func2():
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
func3():
  8           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

The functions are identical. Thus there is no way you could distinguish between them, even by inspecting the functions themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.  The following functions all return the same value, `None`:

```
def a(): return None  # Explicitly return, explicitly with the value None
def b(): return       # Explicitly return, implicitly with the value None
def c(): pass         # Implicitly return, implicitly with the value None
```

You can't differentiate between the values returned by these functions because they all return the same thing.

Further reading: [Python — return, return None, and no return at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15300550/501250)

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically asking about `dict.get()`:

```
sentinel = object()
dict(a=1).get("b", sentinel)
```

Well written "lookup" APIs will either work that way (let you pass a custom 'not found' value) or raise some exception.

Else, well, no, `None` is `None`, period.