# Python: "return" in functions

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, return

Our professor told us that **return** should always be included, *BUT* there are some instances that do not "require" **return** *at all* (at least that's what I think). The way I understand it is, **return** sends a value of whatever is in front of it (assuming it has a value; otherwise it doesn't return anything?). But I've come across some functions that function only as a **print**er, e.g. you have defined a function that, when called upon prints a certain element of a list, and it doesn't matter where the list is (if it's inside the function, before the function, or even after the function) as long as it is created before the line where you call the said function, and this function didn't contain a **return** and why would it? I mean the only purpose of this function is to print and nothing else. So, after reading what I've written so far, can you tell me if I am misunderstanding something or is **return** "supposed" to be there no matter what? I mean even if I included **return**, what would it *return*? I haven't seen any function (so far) that just has a return with nothing in front of it.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/python-return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all

Comment: Simple answer here. Your professor said that return should always be included. Your professor is wrong.

Comment: A return *is* always included; in the absence of an explicit `return` statement (or in the presence of an empty `return`), Python functions/methods implicitly `return None`.

Comment: @Kevin thank you, that was a clear answer to what the professor said. I think I understand now, excluding a return and including a return with None is the same thing because both return "None". Thank you all

Comment: There are quite a few "golden rules" that teachers keep on inflicting to newbies without explanations and whatever the context.  In the best case, your teacher's intent is to force you to think about what your function should return and why. In the worst case... well, bad news, not all teachers should teach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take your example about a function printing a value

```
def func():
    print 'hello'

def func():
    print 'hello'
    return None
```

Both of these functions are technically the same as both of them return None

Check this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) for `function basics` which makes a point about return

> The statement return [expression] exits a function, optionally passing
>   back an expression to the caller. A return statement with no arguments
>   is the same as return None.

So

```
def func():
    print 'hello'
    return
```

is also the same as above two examples

Comment: Thank you for the link in basics, and for the example I tried both of your examples in Wing IDE and got the same result.

Comment: @DickArmstrong you are welcome :)