# How to remove parameter from string?

Tags: python

School assignment asking you to enter name and string. Use the name to determine the initials and remove the initials from the string. Print the original name, original string, initials, and resulting string.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

1. chars doesn't seem to appear in print "Initials are %s..." in the first function
2. can't figure out how to delete the parameter chars from txt.

Code:

```
def main():
    global chars, txt, fullName
    fullName = raw_input("Please input your name: ")
    txt = raw_input("Type in any string: ")
    chars = ''
    getInitials(fullName)
    print "Full name is %s. Original String is %s" % (fullName, txt)
    removeChars(txt,chars)
    print "Initials are %s. Resulting string is %s" %(chars, txt)

def getInitials(fullName):
    chars = ''.join(name[0].upper() for name in fullName.split())
    return

def removeChars(txt, chars):
    for char in txt:
        if char in chars:
            txt = txt.replace(char,'')
    return txt


main()
```

Comment: Note that strings in python are immutable. You cannot modify them, you must create a new one with the changes you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `global` incorrectly (it is generally considered bad practice), and if you `return` something from your functions then completely unnecessary:

```
def main():
    fullName = raw_input("Please input your name: ")
    txt = raw_input("Type in any string: ")
    chars = getInitials(fullName)
    sv = removeChars(txt, chars)
    print "Full name is %s. Original String is %s" % (fullName, txt)
    print "Initials are %s. Resulting string is %s" % (chars, sv)

def getInitials(fullName):
    chars = ''.join(name[0].upper() for name in fullName.split())
    return chars

def removeChars(txt, chars):
    for char in txt:
        if char in chars:
            txt = txt.replace(char, '')
    return txt 

main()
```

Though `removeChars` isn't very efficient because strings are immutable so each replace would create a new string. You could do the same as what you did with `getInitials` with a conditional e.g.:

```
def removeChars(txt, chars):
    return ''.join(char for char in txt if char.upper() not in chars)
```

Note: you probably meant to `upper()` the comparison

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few important things:

- In `getInitials()`, you are are returning `None`, not your `chars` variable. Change your `return` statement to be `return chars`
- In your `main` function, you are calling `getInitials`, but not utilizing a return value. Since `removeChars` is expecting `chars` and you initially set it to an empty string, nothing is being removed.

Change the following:

```
getInitials(fullName)
```

to:

```
chars = getInitials(fullName)
```

- Your `removeChars()` function is returning a result, but you don't capture that result in `main`.

Change:

```
removeChars(txt,chars)
```

to:

```
txt = removeChars(txt, chars)
```

---

There are a few things to be aware of here:

- `txt = removeChars(txt, chars)` is not changing `txt`, it is assigning a completely new value. It just happens to use the same variable name. In your original post, you had a print statement that utilized `sv` as a variable name: `print "Initials are %s. Resulting string is %s" %(chars, sv)`, if you assigned the results of `removeChars` to `sv`, you'd get the same output and the original string will still be available to you in `txt`.
- Remove your `global` statement.
- Your original return in `getInitials` was an empty return statement. This returns `None`. A function without a return statement also returns `None`. More details are available in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/python-return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all)
- Your `removeChars` is inefficient, since strings are immutable. That means the variable is recreating the string repeatedly. For a small example program like this, though, it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean like this?

```
def main():

    fullName = input("Please input your full name: ")
    txt = input("Type in any string: ")

    initials = '.'.join(name[0].upper() for name in fullName.split())

    print(fullName)
    print (txt)
    print(initials)

main()
```

You didnt have to -1 me I was just trying to help.