# Do some functions take return and other not in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why some statements require and RETURN and others do not? Like below, I wrote this and  l1.append(val) doesn't need a return but for example l1[val] does?

Does it just depend on the variable?

```
L = [1,3,5,7,9,11, 2] 

print 'Original List =', L
def change_list(l1, val, decision):
    if decision == 'append':
        return l1[val]
    elif decision == 'ret':
        l1.append(val)
    elif decision == 'instance':
        return l1.count(val)
    elif decision == 'sort':
        l1.sort()
    return l1
res=change_list(L, 2, 'append')
print 'Output =', res
```

However if I change it to the following (remove the return) it breaks! Wh does this happen given some of the conditions need a return to work, some do not?:

L = [1,3,5,7,9,11, 2]

```
print 'Original List =', L
def change_list(l1, val, decision):
    if decision == 'append':
        l1[val]
    elif decision == 'ret':
        l1.append(val)
    elif decision == 'instance':
        return l1.count(val)
    elif decision == 'sort':
        l1.sort()
    return l1
res=change_list(L, 2, 'append')
print 'Output =', res
```

Comment: This link should answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/python-return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all

Comment: it depends on your purpose, what you gonna do with it

Comment: What do you mean it does not need a return? If your `decision == 'ret'` condition is met, you are appending to li and then you are returning `li`. So I do not see where you are drawing your conclusion from.

Comment: @idjaw if i remove the return from the "return l1[val]" - and change the input of the function at bottom to "append" it doesn't work? This is why I'm confused that .append doesn't need to have a return before it but l1[val] does!

Comment: @Phil Sorry, I have no idea what you are trying to explain. I would suggest editing your question to give more explicit examples. Maybe it's just me, but I'm having a hard time following what your problem is.

Comment: @idjaw sorry my bad! examples coming!

Comment: Edited the question! Hopefully clearer now!

Comment: @Phil Now please explain what "it breaks" means. :)

Comment: @idjaw the output went from the single digit (correct) to returning the full list instead (given I've asked it to return the full list at the end)!

Comment: oh......you only need to include the return when the list is being returned I think i.e. append, sort but NOT count, [1] etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that `l1.append(val)` affects the original object. As in, calling `.append(val)` goes to the array that you passed to your `change_list` function and does it to your original `L` array. Where as `l1[val]` only asks your original `L` for the value. So it must be returned