# Returning the recursive call for a void Python function

Tags: python, function

Assuming a function has a void return type (i.e. it doesn't return a value so its return value is `None`), is there a difference between

```
def f(x): return f(x_) if not stopping
```

and

```
def f(x): f(x_) if not stopping
```

where `stopping` is some stopping condition and `x_` is some input to `f`?

Comment: There is no difference, as long as `f` always returns `None`. If a function has no explicit `return` statement, it implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: Right so the second one is `f(x_) if not stopping; return None`. I'm wondering if the stack calls are different, although without TCE I assume not

Comment: A relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/python-return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all

Comment: Well, both. are equivalent in that they are `SyntaxErrors`. In any event, there is no concept of a return type for a Python function. Python is a dynamically typed language. They would not be equivalent depending on how you interpret what you mean.

Comment: But you need to `return` your recursive call, if you want the caller to have access to it's value. Likely, if it is `None` you don't need that, but you *might* (e.g. `None` is a base-case).

Comment: In the question I made clear that the function doesn't have a return value (or since every function in python has a return value, that value is `None`). 

RE syntax I just figured it'd be easier to read this way. Assume there's also an else

Comment: Also, recursion is a terrible way to implement a simple loop in Python. Use a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that there is no difference between the two. Both return `None` and the stack is the same.