# Why does this function change my dictionary to None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a practice program to add items from a list to a existing dictionary

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        inventory[i] = inventory.get(i,0) + 1

stuff = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
loot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
stuff = addToInventory(stuff, loot)
```

Why is stuff changed to None after running this?

Comment: You're not returning anything, thus `None`.

Comment: So just change the last line to `addToInventory(stuff, loot)`, without assigning the returned None to `stuff`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/python-return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact your code is almost good you have just one mistake.
Dictionary in python are mutable then when you modify it in your fonction your modifying the one you pass as argument. But because your function do not return anything when you write:

```
stuff = addToInventory(stuff, loot)
```

you assign stuff to None.

you have two choice:
return the dictionary at the end of the function:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        inventory[i] = inventory.get(i,0) + 1
    return inventory
```

or do not reassign stuff:

```
 addToInventory(stuff, loot)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no return statement in your function so it returns nothing - `None`.

Solution? Add return statement in your function

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
         inventory[i] = inventory.get(i,0) + 1
    return inventory
```