# Why is my enclosed area function giving "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' "?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, python-3.6, nonetype

I want to write a function `func(m1, b1, m2, b2, m3, b3)` that takes six int or float values representing **3 lines** in the following manner:

- y = m1 * x + b1
- y = m2 * x + b2
- y = m3 * x + b3

… and return the area enclosed by these lines. Although I believe my approach is okay, I keep getting this `NoneType` error for some reason:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Below is the approach I followed (I am a complete novice, so your detailed comments/explanation would be very helpful):

```
#First helping function: FIND POINTS OF INTERSECTION
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#This function takes four int or float values representing two lines 
#and returns the x value of the point of intersection of the two lines. 
#If the lines are parallel, or identical, the function should return 
#None. 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

def f(m1,b1,m2,b2):

    if m1 == m2:  
        return None

    else:
        return (b2 - b1)/(m1 - m2)   



#Second helping function: FIND LENGTH (DISTANCE BETWEEN POINTS)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
#This function takes four int or float values representing two points 
#and returns the distance between those points.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

def dist(x1,y1,x2,y2):

    return 

    D = ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)


#3RD Helping function:  FIND AREA ENCLOSED BY 3 LINES 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
#This function takes three int or float values representing side 
#lengths of a triangle, and returns the area of that triangle using 
#Heron's formula
#-----------------------------------------------------------------    
def heron(D1,D2,D3): 

    p = (D1 + D2 + D3)*0.5    
    # where p is half the perimeter 
    area = (p*(p-D1)*(p-D2)*(p-D3))**0.5

    return area 



#Finally, the last function:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
#This function makes use of the helping functions above and connects 
#everything together 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------

def func(m1,b1,m2,b2,m3,b3):

#Using 1st helping function:
#---------------------------
    x1  = f(m1, b1, m2, b2)
    x2  = f(m1, b1, m3, b3)
    x3  = f(m2, b2, m3, b3)

    #---

    y1 = m1*x1 + b1
    y2 = m2*x2 + b2
    y3 = m3*x3 + b3


 #Using 2nd helping function:
 #---------------------------

    D1 = dist(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    D2 = dist(x1,y1,x3,y3)
    D3 = dist(x2,y2,x3,y3)


#Using 3rd helping function:
#---------------------------
    return heron(D1,D2,D3)


print(func(0,20,-2,50,0.5,-10))
```

Comment: FYI: Your question is attracting "close" votes because all those comments have made your code too verbose to be quickly read and understood by experienced (but busy) answerers. Taking all the comments and most of the blank lines out reduces the size from 80 lines to a much more manageable 26.

Comment: (of course, if the comments actually help to explain what's going on, they should instead be written as prose in the body of the question)

Comment: Thanks a lot Zero Piraeus! I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the traceback your code fails with:

```
$ python3.6 heron.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heron.py", line 82, in <module>
    print(func(0,20,-2,50,0.5,-10))
  File "heron.py", line 79, in func
    return heron(D1,D2,D3)
  File "heron.py", line 40, in heron
    p = (D1 + D2 + D3)*0.5    
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Tracebacks help you out a lot (so always include them in Stack Overflow questions). This one tells you that your `TypeError` was raised on line 40:

```
    p = (D1 + D2 + D3)*0.5
```

… so, given the error message `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`, it's obvious that at least a couple of `D1`, `D2` and `D3` must somehow be `None`. These values are created on lines 72-74:

```
    D1 = dist(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    D2 = dist(x1,y1,x3,y3)
    D3 = dist(x2,y2,x3,y3)
```

… so it looks like `dist()` is the culprit. Let's see:

```
def dist(x1,y1,x2,y2):

    return 

    D = ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
```

And, here's your problem. The bare `return` on line 27 terminates the function [and returns `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15300550), before the line assigning to `D` gets a chance to run at all. Here's a fixed version:

```
def dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5
```

(note that I've also added the missing square-root operation so that it returns the correct result)

The program now runs:

```
$ python3.6 heron.py
0.0
```

… printing an area of 0.0, which is, er, wrong. The reason for *that* is different from the exception you asked about, so I'll stop here, except to hint that you might want to look a bit more carefully at this block of code:

```
#Using 1st helping function:
#---------------------------
    x1  = f(m1, b1, m2, b2)
    x2  = f(m1, b1, m3, b3)
    x3  = f(m2, b2, m3, b3)
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st Helping function: Find point of intersection:**

This function takes four int or float values representing two lines and returns the x value of the point of intersection of the two lines. If the lines are parallel, or identical, the function should return None.

```
def noParallel(m1,b1,m2,b2):

    if m1 == m2:
        return None


else:
    x = (b2 - b1)/(m1 - m2)
    return x
```

**2nd Helping function: Find distance between two points:**

This function takes four int or float values representing two points and returns the distance between those points.

```
def dist(x1,y1,x2,y2):

    z = (x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2
    return z**0.5
```

**3rd Helping function: Find enclosed area using Heron's formula**

This function takes three int or float values representing side lengths of a triangle, and returns the area of that triangle using Heron's formula

```
def heron(D1,D2,D3): 

    p = (D1 + D2 + D3)*0.5    
    #where p is half the perimeter 
    area = (p*(p-D1)*(p-D2)*(p-D3))**0.5

    return area
```

**Putting everything together:**

```
def overall(m1,b1,m2,b2,m3,b3):  #Calling functions into functions 

    x1 = noParallel(m1,b1,m2,b2)
    x2 = noParallel(m2,b2,m3,b3)
    x3 = noParallel(m1,b1,m3,b3)

    print(x1)
    print(x2)
    print(x3)
```

The purpose of the following if-statement is to capture the case were lines do not form a triangle, notify user and terminate code. Without this if-statement, the code will crash and you will get a `TYPE ERROR` because (y = int * None) when the three lines do not form a triangle

```
 if x1 == None or x2 == None or x3 == None:
            print("Lines do not form a triangle")
            return None
```

Substitute in y

```
    y1 = m1*x1 + b1  
    y2 = m3*x2 + b3  #OR y2 = m2*x2 + b2 
    y3 = m3*x3 + b3


    print(y1)
    print(y2)
    print(y3)

    D1 = dist(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    D2 = dist(x1,y1,x3,y3)
    D3 = dist(x2,y2,x3,y3)

    print(D1)
    print(D2)
    print(D3)

    overall = heron(D1,D2,D3)
    return overall

    print(overall(0,10,-4,100,4,-100))
```

[Area enclosed by three lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Oqyk.png)