# How to declare procedure/function hybrid in MyPy

Tags: python-3.x, option-type, type-hinting, mypy, static-typing

I've got a function which might return a value (then it must be an int) or behaves like a procedure (i. e. it doesn't call return at all, effectively returning `None` then).  You might have guessed, it is the `main()` function in this well-known pattern:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

The function `sys.exit()` is prepared for this, it accepts `int` and `None` equally.

Some `main()` functions just do things and terminate without an explicit `return`, others `return` an explicit `int`.  I'd like to declare this in a constant typing so that changing my `main()` from "not returning anything" to "return an exit code" doesn't mean I have to adjust the typing declaration.

My trials:

```
def main(argv: List[str]) -> Optional[int]:
    print_something()
```

(Then MyPy complains about missing `return` statement.)

```
def main(argv: List[str]) -> Union[int, None]:
    print_something()
```

(The same as above.)

```
def main(argv: List[str]) -> Optional[int]:
    print_something()
    return
```

("error: Return value expected" :rage:)

```
def main(argv: List[str]) -> Optional[int]:
    print_something()
    return None
```

(Aww, come on.  But works, yeah.  I'm not happy with the useless `return None` in the end.  I think `Optional` already makes it clear that nothing might be returned.)

```
def main(argv: List[str]) -> Any:
    print_something()
```

(Works of course, but using `Any` is too general.  Returning e. g. a string accidentally would not be found by the static type checker.)

Is there any way I didn't think of yet to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

> (Aww, come on. But works, yeah. I'm not happy with the useless `return None` in the end. I think Optional already makes it clear that nothing might be returned.)

I would argue that `Optional` makes it clear that it might return the optional value.  IE. `int`.  I believe that you still have to put the expected return value.  In this case it would be `None`.

There is a good discussion about `None` as a return value [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300671)

See also [mypy docs](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#strict-optional) regarding strict optional types and none checking