# Is it a good practice to add a return statement even when it’s not necessary?

Tags: python, return, coding-style

I was looking at some python code at work where somebody has used a return statement even though it was not necessary. It kind of looked like this:

```
def printSomething():
    print(“......”)
    .
    .
    return
```

This was done for many such functions. I know this does not make any difference to the output of the function. But, is it a good practice to do so? Or just some programmer idiosyncrasy?

Comment: It's programmer idiosyncrasy because there is no difference between a simple return and no return.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/python-return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all : pretty much the same question, but with every explanation you need

Answer (score 1):

No this does absolutely nothing and I would even say its confusing, as in not pythonic, even though it might look ok to a C programmer.

You can safely remove it.

Comment: Care to elaborate on why it can be confusing?

Comment: In general the convention seen in most python programs is that a function that only has side effects does not return, in contrast to C for example where a plain `return` is usual (or was back when I had a clue about it)