# As per Python standards, do we need a `return` statement if function does not return anything

Tags: python, conventions, coding-style

I am having a question regarding return statement for a function. Does python standards say to have a return statement for a function if it does not return anything. Nothing is stopping to write or don't write return but need to know what make a good code

Below is the example code

```
def test():
   print("Hello")
   return
```

or

```
def test():
    print("Hello")
```

Which approach is more conventional in Python?

Comment: If your function isn't supposed to return anything, you do not need a `return` statement. Your first function looks weird.

Comment: And "pythogenic" does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @khelwood: Maybe we shoud use "pythopathic" ;)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51), consistency  is key – you should explicitly return `None` in your function when other code paths (such as an `if` branch) returns anything.

> Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable).

So in your case, you should have:

```
def test():
    print("Hello")
```

Or, if you add more functionality to this function and return something, you should have:

```
def test(foo):
  if foo is not None:
    print("Hello")
    return foo
  return None
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't return anything, by default it will return `None` by default, But the value is not meant to be caught.
You can read it here
[return, return None, and no return at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all)

Answer (score 0):

`return` keyword is used when you return anything from your function & it return where the function call occur. Otherwise it useless to use.