# python functions with no return from the functions

Tags: python, function, python-import, python-object

What is the type of the object that Python functions use, when a function does not return a "useful" object?
For example:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return, return None, and no return at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all)

Answer (score 1):

Missing return statement is the same as returning None

```
>>> sleep(2) is None
True
```

Comment: thanks michael for yr time but i just want to know the answer for,What is the type of the object that Python functions use, when a function does not return a "useful" object?

Comment: @NajeemFazil the type of `None` is `NoneType`.