# I've got a "None" when composing functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

- Hello, I'm extremely new to Python and wanted to try out the newly taught functions, and cobble up this:

```
def print_thrice(a):
    print(a)
    print(a)
    print(a)
def prt(a,b):
    print_thrice(a)
    print(b) 
print_thrice(prt("Name:","Age:"))
```

I expected it to print out `Name: Name: Name: Age:` (with linebreaks of course) 9 times, but what I got turns to be

```
Name:
Name:
Name:
Age:
None
None
None
```

What I had in mind was to have 9 of `Name: Name: Name: Age:`, so I tried to `print_thrice` the already printed thrice `Name:`along with`Age:` in `prt("Name:","Age:")`. The first 3 evidently appeared, which I guess means that the first batch of `print_thrice` worked, but I have no idea why I'd be getting three Nones afterwards.

Eventually I gave up and just did 3 lines of  `prt("Name:","Age:")` instead of `print_thrice(prt("Name:","Age:"))`, and it seemed to work fine.
Can anyone please explain what I did wrong?

Comment: The return value of prt is None since it returns nothing. This is why you see None being printed. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15300550/5079316

Comment: you just need to call `prt("Name:", "Age:"))`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? prt() returns None, that’s why you get 3 Nones after your desire output.

Comment: Others have already answered your question.  I just want to welcome you to the SO. Please do not get discouraged by the negative score.

Comment: I guess what I had in mind was to have 9 of `Name: Name: Name: Age:`, so I tried to `print_thrice` the already printed thrice `Name:` along with `Age:` in `prt("Name:","Age:")`. The first 3 evidently appeared, which I guess means that the first batch of `print_thrice` worked, but I have no idea why I'd be getting three Nones afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Function is a callable object in Python and it has a return value. If you explicitly did not ask something to return by the function, it returns None by default.  
I presume this may be what you were trying to do; If not, please leave a comment.

```
def print_thrice(argumentOne, argumentTwo):

    return '\n'.join(f'I am {argumentOne}  and I am {argumentTwo} years old' for _ in range(3))

print(print_thrice("George","25")) # caling the function print_thrice



I am George  and I am 25 years old
I am George  and I am 25 years old
I am George  and I am 25 years old
```