# Returning numpy array returns NoneType

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So i have a function that makes a numpy ndarray, i need to return this array but when i do so, it gives me a NoneType in the other function from which i called it, it looks something like this:

```
def kMeans(dataSet, kMin, kMax):
    for k in range(kMin,kMax +1):
        centeroids = np.random.choice(dataSet, k)
        oldClusters = []
        clusters = np.array(findClosestCenteroids(dataSet, centeroids))

        finalizedClusters = kMeansAlgorithm(dataSet, centeroids, clusters, oldClusters, k)
        print(type(finalizedClusters))


def kMeansAlgorithm(dataset,centeroids, currCluster, oldCluster, k):
    idx = np.lexsort((currCluster[:, 0], currCluster[:, 1]))
    currentClusters = currCluster[idx]  
    change = np.array_equal(currentClusters, oldCluster)  
    oldClusters = np.copy(currentClusters)
    totalCount = 0
    for i in range(k): #vind het aantal items in een cluster
        count = np.count_nonzero(currentClusters == str(i)) 
        centeroids[i] = currentClusters[totalCount+ round(count/2)][0]
        totalCount = totalCount + count
    if change == True:
        print(type(currentClusters))
        return currentClusters
    print(change)
    newClusters = np.array(findClosestCenteroids(dataset, centeroids))
    kMeansAlgorithm(dataset, centeroids, newClusters, oldClusters, k)
```

Now this prints:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'NoneType'>
```

How do i properly return a numpy array?

Comment: add `return array1` at the end of `fun1`?

Comment: This isn't enough code (and has a syntax error `array 2`) to see what's wrong; you can directly return a numpy array and it'll work fine, so there is some error in your code!

Comment: i still want to use array1 in fun1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return, return None, and no return at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all)

Comment: Please show *actual* code. What appears here has multiple typos; for example `array1 = fun2():` is a syntax error.

Comment: Allright, will do, i see the error yea, thought it might be easier to read for others like this

Comment: Your function `kMeansAlgorithm` doesn't return anything if `change == False`

Comment: True, but eventually it becomes true, otherwise i would never get the print statement from the kMeans function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, had a recursive function and forgot that you always need to return the function instead of just calling it again