# Go through cells of a single column, and apply a formula to them if they meet a certain condition using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, data-cleaning

Doing some data cleaning in a CSV file. I want to convert some CSV data into HTML before uploading the data to a website.

I'm going through every cell in the column called 'Details' in a pandas dataframe.

If a cell starts with this character combination: **\r\r\n \t**, then I want to replace it with this: **<ul><li>**

> ```
> df2 = df.copy()
>
> def startswith_replace (x, a, b):
>
>     if x.startswith(a):
>         x.replace(a, b)       
>
> df2['Details'] = df2['Details'].
>       apply(lambda x: startswith_replace(x, '\\r\\r\\n \\t', '\<ul\>\<li\>'))
> ```

When I run this, however, every cell in the 'Details' column is replaced with 'None' as its value.

Comment: Your function doesn't have a `return` statement and therefore returns `None` implicitly, see [return, return None, and no return at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all)

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished using the built-in [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) without needing to define your own function, with just a little regex

(`^` to only check the start of the string and `()` optionally to set it as a capture group, but if you decide you want to replace all occurrences both can be omitted and the raw string passed)

```
df

    A   B   A   Details
0   1   2   3   \r\r\n \t
1   4   5   6   lkjn \r\r\n \t
2   7   8   9   abcdefg

df['Details']=df['Details'].str.replace(r'^(\r\r\n \t)','\<ul\>\<li\>')

    A   B   A   Details
0   1   2   3   \<ul\>\<li\>
1   4   5   6   lkjn \r\r\n \t
2   7   8   9   abcdefg
```