# How to use the defined function twice withought an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I defined a function, which could swap the elements in the string.
When I used the swapx function twice, there is an error.
Here is my code.

```
def swapx(lst):
    helper=lst[0]
    lst[0]=lst[-1]
    lst[-1]=helper

s=list("python")
swapx(s)
print(s)
swapx(swapx(s))

['n', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'p']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-f89e12aa1f31> in <module>
      7 swapx(s)
      8 print(s)
----> 9 swapx(swapx(s))

<ipython-input-100-f89e12aa1f31> in swapx(lst)
      1 def swapx(lst):
----> 2     helper=lst[0]
      3     lst[0]=lst[-1]
      4     lst[-1]=helper
      5 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: With no explicit `return`, any function will implicitly return `None`...

Comment: Also relevant and interesting: [return, return None, and no return at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15300550/6045800)

Comment: Yeah, I'm clear now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is not returning anything, so by doing

```
swapx(swapx(s))
```

you are trying to apply your function to `None`, and not to a list. Try this:

```
def swapx(lst):
    helper=lst[0]
    lst[0]=lst[-1]
    lst[-1]=helper
    return lst

s = list("python")
print(swapx(s))
swapx(s)
print(swapx(swapx(s)))
```

result will be:

```
['n', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'p']
['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

if you run

```
s = list("python")
print(swapx(swapx(s)))
```

result will be

```
['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

so you will get the same list, as the function is applied twice...but it works, you will not get an error

As @LiMar suggested, you can write a more pythonic swap:

```
def swapx(lst):
    lst[0], lst[-1] = lst[-1], lst[0]
    return lst
```

Comment: That is not quite correct. A function without a return statement explicitly returns "None". Not a function object.
Hence the error message "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" it means that you can't use the []-operator on None Type

Comment: @A.Franzen you're right! Sorry for the mistake, I'll correct my answer

Comment: Swap operation can be done without helper `lst[0],lst[-1] = lst[-1], lst[0]`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if you do it like this:

```
def swapx(lst):
    helper=lst[0]
    lst[0]=lst[-1]
    lst[-1]=helper
    return lst

s=list("python")
s = swapx(s)
print(s)
swapx(s)
print(s)
swapx(s)
print(s)
```

Comment: While this solves the problem, it's generally discouraged to post just code without an explanation.