# Functions in a class returns None without return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

i just learnt classes in python programming (learning still) and started experimenting with it and found my code gives a none statement in output but didn't use any **return** in my functions

MY CODE

```
class GreetingMessage:
    def welcome_message(self):
        print("you are welcome to python")
    def thank_you_message(self):
        print("Ok Bye Thank You")
    def on_process_message(self):
        print("process is on progress")
        

msg1 = GreetingMessage()

print(msg1.welcome_message())
print(msg1.on_process_message())
print(msg1.thank_you_message())
```

**OUTPUT:**

you are welcome to python
None
process is on progress
None
Ok Bye Thank You
None

Comment: Functions return None by default, even if you don’t include a return statement.

Comment: You are printing the return values of your functions in the last 3 lines. They don't have a return function so it prints "none". Either remove the prints around those functions calls, or make the functions return a string to print and not print by themselves.

Comment: I hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300671/2681662

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a return function in your code, it will automatically return None. However, you aren't obligated to print the result of the function you are using, if it already prints by itself. You can just write instead :

```
msg1.welcome_message()
msg1.on_process_message()
msg1.thank_you_message()
```

Answer (score 0):

A function will return `None` automatically until and unless you've written a return statement. If you have written `print` statement, then no need to write print again outside the class. Just call the method

```
msg1.welcome_message()
msg1.on_process_message()
msg1.thank_you_message()
```

If at all you want a return statement, then you'll have to write print outside the class while calling the method

Edited code would be:

```
class GreetingMessage:
    def welcome_message(self):
        return "you are welcome to python"
    def thank_you_message(self):
        return "Ok Bye Thank You"
    def on_process_message(self):
        return "process is on progress"
    

msg1 = GreetingMessage()

print(msg1.welcome_message())
print(msg1.on_process_message())
print(msg1.thank_you_message())
```