# Error while trying to shuffle a deck of cards

Tags: python, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle a deck of cards and I keep getting this error which I don't know how to solve. I am new to python and OOP so I think this should just be something that I overlooked.

This is my code:

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []

        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                card_created = Card(suit, rank)
                self.deck.append(card_created)

    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ""
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_comp += "\n"+ card.__str__()
        return "The deck has: " + deck_comp

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal_one(self):
        return self.deck.pop()

new_deck = Deck()

print(new_deck.shuffle())
```

When I run the program I only get "None". However, before shuffling the deck, I get all the existing cards in order.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `shuffle()` does not `return` a value. `new_deck.shuffle()` then `print(new_deck)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return, return None, and no return at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/return-return-none-and-no-return-at-all)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you, it was literally just that

Comment: @G.Anderson That question is about different ways of returning `None`. It doesn't directly address OP's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `shuffle()` function doesn't return any value (and neither does `random.shuffle()`, which shuffles the list in-place).

Instead, you should perform the call to `.shuffle()` and `print()` on separate lines:

```py
new_deck.shuffle()
print(new_deck.deck)
```

Comment: This solved the issue, thank you so much