# Python | while is repeating old data, even if False

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to create a loop if the condition is not met. If it is met at minimum second run, the print from my last run is also in my output, like in the example its printing the same print() that was printed in the previous run in addition to the result of the second run.

```
secretcode= r.randint(1, 100)

print("\n\n\nWelcome to the lottery!\n")
print("Guess a number from 1 to 100!")
print(secretcode)


def usrinput():
    usrinputnumber = int(input("Your number: "))
    schleife(usrinputnumber)


def schleife(usrinputnumber):
    while not (secretcode == usrinputnumber):
        if usrinputnumber > secretcode:
            print("Awh damn! Your number is too high!!")
            usrinput()

        else:
            print("Unlucky! YOur number is too low!")
            usrinput()


    print("Congratz! You guessed the number!!")


usrinput()
```

Everything works fine when I do an "if" instead the while and using the last print as "else"

Example:
The "secretcode" is 55.
As input I type 45.
The console prints "Unlucky! The number is too low!"
Now I type 55.
The console prints the "Congratz" message AND the "too low" message. Why the "too low" message?

I know functions are not needed, I just wanna know what the problem is and if I can run it in functions like I did.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use `while` loop here as `usreingabe` nor `Geheimzahl` don't change inside of the loop. Apart from that, it's not very clear what is your problem. In the future, I'd suggest using English for your code (variables/functions names) especially for StackOverflow as not everybody here speaks german which makes it much harder to help.

Comment: I think usrinput() should be in the while loop, and should only run **once**  per number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This control flow does not make any sense. Please keep in mind that calling a function is **not at all like** telling the code to "go here next". It is a *request to compute a result*, which you will then *use in the current context*. It is also important to understand that each **call to** a function is a separate process. The function is not like a machine that is set in motion when called, but instead like a set of instructions *that will be followed by a new executor, each time*.

---

When `usrinput()` is called from within `schleife`, right now `usrinput` will call `schleife` again. That *separate call* has its *own complete set of local variables*, including the `usrinputnumber` parameter. Supposing that the user typed the correct `secretcode`, *this* call to `schleife` will escape its `while` loop, print the success message...

... and then `return` back the result of its computation ([which is `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300550/)) to its caller, the call of `usrinput`, which returns its result (also `None`) to the *other* call of `schleife`, which also hadn't finished yet. And, within that call, nothing has changed *its* local value for `usrinputnumber`, so the loop continues.

---

Remember that functions are supposed to do one thing. The purpose of `usrinput` is to get the user's input. The task performed by `schleife` is **not a logical part of that task**, therefore `usrinput` **should not call `schleife`**.

Instead: `usrinput`, instead of trying to feed the result of its computation (i.e., the user's input) to the "next step", should `return` that result - *that is what `return` is for*.

On the other hand, `schleife` can still call `usrinput`, because "get new user input to see if it matches this time" *is* a logical part of its task. Since the value will be `return`ed, we need to make use of that by *explicitly assigning it* to `usrinputnumber`. We can also see that since `schleife` will be calling `usrinput` in the loop anyway, it makes as much sense to get the initial value that way, too.

---

Putting it together, we get:

```
def usrinput():
    return int(input("Your number: "))

def schleife():
    usrinputnumber = usrinput()
    while not (secretcode == usrinputnumber):
        if usrinputnumber > secretcode:
            print("Awh damn! Your number is too high!!")
            usrinputnumber = usrinput()
        else:
            print("Unlucky! YOur number is too low!")
            usrinputnumber = usrinput()
    print("Congratz! You guessed the number!!")

schleife()
```

Comment: *"each call to a function is a separate process"* is a bit confusing wording

Comment: I'm open to suggestions (I assume you understand the underlying concepts).

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! Thats exactly what Ive been looking for. It seems that I missunderstood functions in some parts.

Comment: it's a common misconception, but it's hard to find a reference question because there isn't a unique, clear representation of the problem in code.