# Search for item in list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, search

So I have this `params`:

```
p = [{'quantity': 1}, {'args': {'id': 12345678, 'age': 12}}]
```

And I want to be able to search for `quantity` and get the value `1` or the `args` key and get its `doctionary` (`{'id': 12345678, 'age: 12}`)

This is what I have try:

```
def search(name: str, params: list[dict]):
    try:
        return next((x[name] for x in params if x), None)
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

I case I search for the value of `quantity`:

```
search(name='quantity', params=p)
```

This return `1`

But in case I want to value of `args`:

```
search(name='args', params=p)
```

This return `None`

Answer (score 1):

I have a [set of functions](https://pastebin.com/NRxKRJPn) that you could use for this [ <kbd>`getNestedVal(p, 'args')`</kbd> would return `{'id': 12345678, 'age: 12}` ]...or you can use this generator

```py
def yieldNestedVals(obj, key):
    if isinstance(obj, str): return
    try: yield obj[key]
    except: pass
    if isinstance(obj, dict): obj = obj.values()
    for i in (obj if hasattr(obj, '__iter__') else []):
        for v in yieldNestedVals(i, key): yield v
```

inside <kbd>`search`</kbd> like

```py
def search(name, params, defaultVal=None):
    for v in yieldNestedVals(params, name): return v # return 1st generated value
    return defaultVal # if nothing if generated
```

<sup>[ Ofc you can omit both the `defaultVal` parameter and the last line if you want to just return `None` when nothing if found, since that is the [default behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15300550/6146136) when a function doesn't come across a `return` statement. ]</sup>

Now <kbd>`search('args', p)`</kbd> should also return `{'id': 12345678, 'age: 12}` and you can try it with other keys as well:

```py
# p = [{'quantity': 1}, {'args': {'id': 12345678, 'age': 12}}]
{k: search(k, p) for k in ['quantity', 'args', 'id', 'age', 'dneKey']}
```

would return

> ```py
> {'quantity': 1,
>  'args': {'id': 12345678, 'age': 12},
>  'id': 12345678,
>  'age': 12,
>  'dneKey': None}
> ```