# calling method from a class does not work

Tags: python

This class Employee is supposed to print 50001 when the method of apply_method i called. however it's printed "None". I am tuck please help.

```py
class Employee:
    
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@mycompany.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last)

    def apply_method(self):
        self.pay =  int(self.pay + 1) 

empl_1 =Employee('John','Gan',50000)
print(empl_1.apply_method())
```

Comment: What output were you expecting? Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067013/is-it-possible-to-not-return-anything-from-a-function-in-python

Answer (score 1):

It's because you need a `return` in `apply_method`

```
class Employee:
    
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@mycompany.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last)

    def apply_method(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay + 1) 
        return self.pay

empl_1 =Employee('John','Gan',50000)
print(empl_1.apply_method()) 
#or print(empl_1.pay)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `return` clause in `apply_method`. Try this;

```
def apply_method(self):
    self.pay =  int(self.pay + 1)
    return self.pay
```

If you want to print an output of a function or method, that function or method needs to return something.

Comment: You should choose one of the answers as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the function is not returning anything. You need to return `self.pay`-

```
def apply_method(self):
    self.pay =  int(self.pay + 1)  
    return self.pay
```