# python string replacement, generating all possible combinations

Tags: python, string, replace, iteration, python-itertools

I work with strings, each having a dynamic amount of optional variables in parenthesis:

```
(?please) tell me something (?please)
```

Now I want to replace the variables with an empty string and get back all possible variations:

```
tell me something (?please)

(?please) tell me something

tell me something
```

The wanted function is supposed to handle multiple, different and an endless amount of variables.

any help highly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried the code from DSM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841652/string-replacement-combinations but it doesn't work on a full sentence, don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the solution at [String Replacement Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841652/string-replacement-combinations) is that solution iterates over each character in the original string, whereas you want to check substrings of the original string.  Thus, you should `split()` your string and iterate over that list.  Also, when you join the list at the end, put the spaces back between the words.  For example,

```
def filler(word, from_char, to_char):    
    options = [(c,) if c != from_char else (from_char, to_char) for c in word.split(" ")] 
    return (' '.join(o) for o in product(*options)) 
list(filler('(?please) tell me something (?please)', '(?please)', ''))
```

This returns

```
['(?please) tell me something (?please)', '(?please) tell me something ', ' tell me something (?please)', ' tell me something ']
```

If you want to omit the line that contains no removals ( the line `'(?please) tell me something (?please)'` ), a hacky solution is simply to remove the first element of the result, since the way `product` works guarantees the first result picks the first element of each option, which corresponds to the line that has no strings removed.

Comment: sorry one more question: how can I do it with several, different and optional variables. iterating in a loop doesn't work for me

Comment: You will need to modify `c != from_char` to make it compare against a list of variables.  Please give it a try, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: you made me do it! `options = [(c,) if c not in from_char else (c, to_char) for c in word.split(" ")] ` thank you