# How do I create a brute force password finder using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

I want to create a brute force password finder using python for ethical reasons, I looked up tutorials on how to do this and all the tutorials I found have variables that contain the password. I want to find the password but I don't know what it is.

So what I want for the code to do is to get the password text-box of any website and take passwords from a list I have and try using them in the text box. I am not sure how to do that, but here is some sample code of what I have so far. Also, I am a somewhat beginner when it comes to coding python, I have a somewhat good grasp of the fundamentals of the language. So depending on how you word your response I might not understand what to do.

Code:

```py
import random
char_list = './password.txt'
password = 'lakers'
def main():
    with open('./password.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            guess_password = random.choices(char_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! "So what I want for the code to do is to get the password text-box of any website and take passwords from a list I have and try using them in the text box" This is a classic problem of "break big problem into small ones and start on the first". I think your question is better phrased as "how to enter text into website login form" but you'll need to pick a library--selenium, pypeteer--for that. Once you have that groundwork laid, you can then worry about brute forcing the password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String Replacement Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841652/string-replacement-combinations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So most websites will use a POST request for their logins. Identify the requests attributes and its path. Then use the `requests` library to make the same request inside your password cracker. Now onto the Password Cracker part. If you are looking for a numerical password cracker that is a lot easier. For example.

```py
import requests

for i in range(1000000):
  requests.post(path, data={"username": username, "password": i})
```

Now this would still remain efficient, however if you're cracking an alphanumerical password it would cross the line into completely redundant and useless. It would take 92 years on a pretty decent CPU to crack an 8 character password.

If you still insist on using an alphanumerical password cracker here would be the code

```py
import itertools
import string

chars = string.printable
attempts = 0
for password_length in range(1, 9):
    for guess in itertools.product(chars, repeat=password_length):
        attempts += 1
        # Make a request to the server with the guess as the password
```

I highly recommend you use Cython to speed up the process. It greatly helps and speeds up by a lot.

Comment: How are you supposed to input the username and password into the website's login boxes?

Comment: Those login pages work on POST requests. It's a lot more lightweight that using selenium or pypeeter.