# Passing method as parameter in Python (Scrapy) - syntax

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Python with some Java/C# background. I encountered the callback syntax in Scrapy tutorial and an unexpected syntax along, which I would like to understand.

In the last line of below code `parse_articles_follow_next_page` is a method and per my imagination I would expect a response parameter is passed there in parentheses like:
 `yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_articles_follow_next_page(someresponseobject))`

What sort of Python syntax is applied there so that it goes without parentheses and passing parameter, where could I read more about  it?

```
def parse_articles_follow_next_page(self, response):
    for article in response.xpath("//article"):
        item = ArticleItem()
        #... extract article data here
        yield item

    next_page = response.css("ul.navigation > li.next-page > a::attr('href')")
    if next_page:
        url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_articles_follow_next_page)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Scrapy [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/request-response.html), one of the parameters to Request can be a callback:

*callback (callable) – the function that will be called with the response of this request (once its downloaded) as its first parameter.*

So you are passing a function. The response parameter will be passed to that function once it is known, by Scrapy's callback mechanism.

Read about passing functions as arguments:
[python function as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289646/python-function-as-a-function-argument)

Or callbacks in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: great, thanks - I might not use it again shortly outside of scrapy - but it is good to know