# Python A function that takes a function as a parameter with its parameters

Tags: python, function, parameters, overloading

Imagine I have a two functions

```
def areaSquare(a,b):
   print( a * b)

def areaCircle(radius):
   print(3.14159 * radius ** 2)
```

And I want to create a third function that is called area.

```
area(areaCircle,radius = 3, repeat = 5)
# prints 3.14159 * 9 five times
area(areaSquare, a = 2, b = 3, repeat = 6)
# prints 2 * 6 six times
```

So the function takes a function as a parameter. Depending on the function which is passed to it as a parameter, it should require additional parameters. Is there a way to achieve this? I know function overloading would be an option. But I do not want to define multiple functions for this purpose.

Comment: I wouldn't use functions but class in this case. Define a class Area with circle and square methods, where you would be able to pass your arguments elegantly.

Comment: you should check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289646/python-function-as-a-function-argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python function as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289646/python-function-as-a-function-argument)

Comment: @JeanRostan: Could you elaborate what you meant? What are the advantages of your method compared to the answer of Willem Van Onsem.

Comment: @MrYouMath I would say readability of code, but it is probably a personal opinion. It also comes more naturally, Willem answer is perfect, but doesn't come to me as fast as custom methods for a class, which allows you to do lots of hacks cleanly, hidden behind classes. Nevertheless, his answer is interesting, but I would suggest you check on OOP (object oriented programming), it will eventually be useful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [*kwargs*](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/) are your friend here. We can define the function such that the remaining parameters are captured in a dictionary named `kwargs`, and then passed to the function we provide. Like:

```
def area(func, repeat, **kwargs):
    for _ in range(repeat):
        func(**kwargs)
```

So all parameters except `func` and `repeat` are stored in the `kwargs` dictionary, and later we call the `func` function (the first argument) with the named parameters.

Note that this will not work (correctly) for functions that require a `func` and/or `repeat` parameter, since we capture these at the `area` function level.

Comment: plus 1 For you quick answer. I will accept the answer as soon as I have tried it out for my problem.

Comment: @MrYouMath: aarrghh.. the functions are not returning, but printing? Why? Usually you only want a very small subset to `print`. It is still possible, but very "unelegant". Anyway, I've made an edit such that it works now.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your method worked like a charm. My functions were a little bit more involved that is why I tried to break it down such that it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. How is this method called programming languages?  And how would it generalize to multiple functions as parameters?

Comment: Well in Python everything is an object (an integer is an object, a string is an object, an class instance is an object, a class itself is an object, etc). As a result you can pass those objects as parameters, and return them as parameters. Usually if functions are *first class citizens*, people call this *functional programming*.