# How to call one specific function which is inside another function?

Tags: python, function

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
def calculations(a,b):
    def add(a,b):
        return a+b
    def subtract(a,b):
        return a-b

def other_function(calculations,c,d):
    return calculations(c,d) + 10

result = other_function(add,10,5)
print(result)
>>> 25
```

This is just a simplified example but I want to be able to let the function "calculations" do 2 different things without passing this choice as a function parameter.

Then, I would like to use this choice as a function parameter to another function "other_function".

Something similar seems to work when defining "calculations" as a class but this is not what I want to use.

Even though it seems not very practical to define "add" and "subtract" inside another function, this is what I want to do.

Comment: "I want to be able to let the function "calculations" do 2 different things without passing this choice as a function parameter" - how will `calculations` know what to do if you don't pass the choice to it?

Comment: Maybe something like calculations().add(a,b) ? Which is not directly a function parameter but just a specification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python function as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289646/python-function-as-a-function-argument)

Comment: @mulaixi I know that a function can be passed as a function argument. This is not my main question.

Comment: @Clapham at that point `calculations` might as well be a class. In fact, the code you pasted will work if it was.

Comment: Your code works fine if you remove functions add and subtract out of function calculations.

Comment: @rdas I know, but does this work when avoiding classes and instead using a function? This is a requirement of my assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the function and it doesn't have to (and **shouldn't be**) inside another function.

This will work just fine if you get rid of the outer function!

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

def subtract(a,b): # you also had a typo here - it's subtrack, not sub_S_track ;)
    return a-b

def other_function(calculations,c,d):
    return calculations(c,d) + 10

result = other_function(add,10,5)
print(result)
```

What happened?

`calculations` in `other_function` is **just a parameter name** (you pass it when calling the function!).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The typo is fixed ;) Even though this might not seem very practical, would it theoretically be possible to include "add" and "subtract" in another function and have it working?

Comment: @Clapham No. `def` defines a scope. Functions inside functions are local, they are like other variables inside that function. Also, Python prefers flatness - as opposed to compiled languages, names are looked up every time something happens. I'll find you a text that comments on that

Comment: @Clapham http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html This is where I found the info about practices from compiled languages that don't work in Python. The thing about flatness is actually from The Zen of Python (do `import this` in the python interpreter): `Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
`

Comment: Thank you, maybe it doesn't work then what I was trying to do. If I get something then I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

you can define one function like this:

```py
def calculate(mode, a, b):
    if mode == "add":
        return a + b
    elif mode == "substract":
        return a - b
```

and you can add whatever operations you want to this function

Comment: The point is that I don't want to add the "mode" as function parameter.

Comment: @Clapham If you don't pass it, how can the function know what to do? Computers are not mind-readers, algorithms need clear instructions what to do.

Comment: There is no way you could specify an operation with just two numbers as the numbers operated on, you definietly need more information for that

Answer (score 0):

You could hand in a string and put the functions in a dictionary:

```
def calculations(key, a,b):
    def add(a, b):
        return a + b
    def substract(a, b)
        return a - b
    fns = {"add": add, "substract": substract}
    return fns[key](a, b)


result = calculations("add", 10, 5)
```

This is pretty wasteful though because you redefine the inner functions every time `calculations` is executed.

Comment: Does this only work when including "key" as function parameter? Couldn't something like - calculations().add(a,b) - work somehow? I know this syntax doesn't work but maybe something similar?

Comment: @Clapham You can't use class syntax for functions. Functions inside other functions are local.

Comment: @h4z3 Is it possible to define these functions to be global?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `namedtuple` to get what you want.

```
from collections import namedtuple
ops = namedtuple('Ops', ['add', 'subtract'])


def add(a, b):
    return a + b


def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b


def calculations():
    return ops(add, subtract)


def other_function(calc, a, b):
    return calc(a, b) + 10


result = other_function(calculations().add, 10, 5)
```

Using a class would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Resulting from all the discussion here, I've figured out what I want. Thank you for your input!

```
def calculations(a,b):

    global add
    def add(a, b):
        return a + b

    global subtract
    def subtract(a, b):
        return a - b

    return add, subtract

def other_function(calculations, a, b):
    e = a + 19
    return calculations(e, b)

a = 10
b = 5

calculations(a,b)
result = other_function(add, a,b)
print(result)
>>>
```

It's by no means pythonic or elegant but satisfied the following conditions which I was looking for:

- two functions - "add", "substract" - inside another function "calculations"
- call one of those functions - "add" - without specifying it as function parameter of "calculations"
- use this chosen function as a parameter for another function "other_function"

Comment: If you make them global, there's no point in making the `def calculations`. It's just a piece of code that does nothing. It definitely doesn't help with readability, so it's also un-pythonic.

Comment: Ok, maybe the assignment doesn't make sense then because I had to follow the requirements stated above. Even though this is useless in terms of fuctionality then, thank you for pointing it out and thank you for your time!