# Why use positional-only parameters in Python 3.8+?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, pep570

A new "positional-only parameters" syntax has been introduced in 3.8.

From [Positional-only parameters](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters) in the documentation:

> There is new syntax (`/`) to indicate that some function parameters must
> be specified positionally (i.e., cannot be used as keyword arguments).
> This is the same notation as shown by `help()` for functions implemented
> in C (produced by Larry Hastings’ [Argument Clinic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) tool).

Why ever use this syntax? Why is it better for the code's user?

It seems to me that this makes it harder for users to specify what their arguments actually mean, if they so desire. Why make it harder on the user?

Comment: Did you read the relevant [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/)?

Comment: Probably a similar reason to keyword-only arguments. If something should only be used in a certain way, allowing you to prevent potentially erroneous usage is good.

Comment: I would like to point out that SO guidelines encourages duplicating even all data on the internet into a form of Q&A. Having done that, the data is much more searchable, and endless docs and forum discussions can be avoided.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To briefly summarize the stated rationales in [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/), the PEP that added positional-only arguments:

1. Many built-in functions implemented in C already did not accept keyword arguments, even before Python 3.8. Allowing positional-only argument allows python code to be consistent with C code
2. Some python classes, such as the constructor for the `dict` type, take arbitrary keyword arguments. If you were to try to define a class with such behavior in python, you would have to write `def __init__(self, **kwds)`, ... except then you can't have a keyword argument named `self`!. Positional-only arguments can avoid this flaw.
3. Some functions don't have any natural name to assign their argument to. Take the `int` constructor. `int(x="3")` is no more readable than `int("3")`. Positional-only arguments allow names that have no inherent meaning to be considered implementation details rather than part of the public API of the module.

There are a few more details in the PEP, but those three points summarize the general reason for the existence of the feature.

Comment: A good example for point 2 is [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). You would not be able to fix an argument named `func` of the function you are passing if the argument `func` of `partial` was not keyword-only.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that people rename their function arguments and then all of the function calls which used keywords no longer work properly.

For example, given a function as follows:

```
def pow(base: float, exponent: int) -> float:
   pass
```

you could write function calls using positional *or* keyword arguments:

```
pow(4.5, 10)
pow(4.5, exponent=10)
pow(exponent=10, base=4.5)
```

If the arguments were subsequently renamed:

```
def pow(base: float, exp: int) -> float:
   """
        CHANGE LOG OR VERSION HISTORY:
           `exponent` renamed to `exp`
   """   
   pass
```

then calls referring to the old argument names would give a `TypeError`:

```
pow(4.5, 10)  # OK
pow(4.5, exponent=10)  # TypeError
pow(exponent=10, base=4.5)  # TypeError
```

One potential rememdy is requiring consumers to use only positional arguments:

```
def pow(base: float, exponent: int, /) -> float:
    pass
```