# Why does function run without paramater?

Tags: python, curses

I'm currently learning curses in python, and I found this piece of code online that is confusing me.

```
import curses

def draw_menu(stdscr):
    # do stuff
    # if you want more code just let me know


def main():
    curses.wrapper(draw_menu)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run this I don't get the expected `missing 1 required positional argument` error, since there is no parameter being passed in the `curses.wrapper(draw_menu)` line. Is this a `curses` thing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `curses.wrapper(draw_menu)` passes a parameter. The parameter is the function `draw_menu` itself. Important: It is the function, not the result of calling the function. This function might be called somewhere in `curses.wrapper` and `curses.wrapper` has to provide a parameter for that call.

Comment: You aren't calling the function anywhere, so you shouldn't expect that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is a datatype, just as much as strings, integers, and so on.

```
def my_function(txt):
  print(txt)
```

here `type(my_function) # => <class 'function'>`

You invoke the code inside the function when you call it with parenthesis : `my_function('hello') # => prints hello`

Until then you can perfectly pass a function as an argument to another function.
And that last one can call the one you passed giving it some parameters.

Like in your case, I'd guess that `curses.wrapper()` creates a screen interface that it passes as argument your `draw_menu()` function.
And you can probably use that screen object to build your curse app.

See this : [Python function as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289646/python-function-as-a-function-argument)

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference between `curses.wrapper(draw_menu)` and `curses.wrapper(draw_menu())`. `curses.wrapper(draw_menu)` calls `curses.wrapper` and passes the function `draw_menu` into it as an argument. In contrast, `curses.wrapper(draw_menu())` would *call* `draw_menu` and pass its return value into `curses.wrapper`.

[`curses.wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.wrapper) will call the function you pass it. From that link:

> Initialize curses and call another callable object, func, which should be the rest of your curses-using application.

E.g., it will call `draw_menu` when `curses` is completely initialized.

Comment: Does the `wrapper` function call the `draw_menu` with a parameter then?

Comment: @Haveaniceday - Yes. It says that in the first paragraph of the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the signature for `curses.wrapper` from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses).

```
curses.wrapper(func, /, *args, **kwargs)
```

It says that you need to give `curses.wrapper` a function reference argument followed by zero or more arguments and keyword arguments.  Your code satisfies those requirements.

Python allows function signatures like this to enable developers  a lot of flexibility regarding what can be passed in by the caller.