# TypeError: warnTime() missing 1 required positional argument: i

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
def warnTime(i):
  i += 1
  print(i)

t = Timer(20, warnTime)
t.start()
```

The rest of the code works just fine, but when it comes to this part, it raises the TypeError.

When I try to get the variable value it does the same thing.
When I try to do `i = 0` before the function it just returns 0.

I tried calling the function with argument, like `warnTime(0)` or `variable = warnTime(0)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: What is `Timer`?

Comment: `Timer` is a module that calls a function once in x seconds (20 in this case)

Comment: Did you import Timer?

Comment: The dupe shows how to pass a default param, not how to actual pass it through the Timer class, don't think that makes it a valid dupe.

Comment: A more fitting title could be : *"How can I pass an argument to a function called by Threading Timer"*.

Comment: So far we don't know that `Timer` is `threading.Timer`. The dupe works in either case, by replacing `Timer(20, warnTime)` by `Timer(20, lambda: warnTime(0))`.

Comment: Yea oke if you consider introducing a Lambda function instead of the proper `args` way, that's fine. Still don't think that's the most clean fix tho.

Comment: Once this is clarified, either add to or replace the linked duplicate list with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415672/python-theading-timer-how-to-pass-argument-to-the-callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [Threading Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer), you'll need to pass the initial value of `i`, change your code to:

```py
from threading import Timer

def warnTime(i):
  i += 1
  print(i)

t = Timer(20, warnTime, args=[0])
t.start()
```

---

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvLCoMwEEX38xV3mVAptt0J@Qt3pYuAic4iD8YB6ddHRXB3z@Hc@tel5E9rUUqCLhL8xHkGp1pEMXIKQjSFiM1LPtGwHQhgPBxex6jCWQ9JpHDXwby7O@/gZV7dt/9Z0ueqXtTY1nY)

Comment: I've read the documentation, I've included that assumption in the asnweer.